# How does drawRect and CGGraphicsContext work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I am working with some stuff in Core Graphic's and I am looking for some additional clarification regarding a couple of topics.

drawRect:
I have an understanding of this and know it is where all of the drawing aspect's of a UIView goes, but am just unclear as to what is happening behind the scene's. What happen's when I create a UIView and fill out drawRect then set another object's UIView to be that custom view? When is drawRect being called?

CGGraphicsContext:
I know what the purpose of this is and understand the concept, but I can't see exactly how it is working. 
For example:

```
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
CGContextClip(context);
CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

The code above is in my app and work's correctly. The thing that confuses me is how it is working. The idea of saving/restoring a context makes sense, but it appears like I am literally saving a context, using that exact same context to make change's, then restoring the same context once again. It just seem's like I am saving a context and then writing on top of that context, only to restore it. How is it getting saved to a point where when you restore it, it is a different instance of the context than what was just used to make changes? You use the same reference of the variable context in every situation.

Lastly I would appreciate any resource's for practice project's or example's on using Core Graphics. I am looking to improve my skill in the matter since I obviously don't have much at the current time.

Comment: For anyone looking for a clearer example of using UIView's drawRect method for rendering graphics and the like, see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26116136/ios-viewcontroller-view-graph-live-with-mutable-array/43798501#43798501

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What happen's when I create a UIView and fill out drawRect then set another object's UIView to be that custom view? When is drawRect being called?

Adding a view to a 'live' view graph marks the view's frame as in need of display. The main run loop then creates and coalesces invalid rects and soon returns to invoke drawing. It does not draw immediately upon invalidation. This is a good thing because resizing, for example, would result in significant overdrawing -- redundant work which would kill many apps' drawing performance. When drawing, a context is created to render to -- which ultimately outputs to its destination.

Graphics Contexts are abstractions which are free to work optimally for their destination -- a destination could be a device/screen, bitmap, PDF, etc.. However, a context handle (`CGContextRef`) itself refers to a destination and holds a set of parameters regarding its state ([these parameters are all documented here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextSaveGState)). These parameter sets operate like stacks: Push = `CGContextSaveGState`, Pop = `CGContextRestoreGState`. Although the context pointer isn't changing, the stack of parameter sets is changing.

As far as resources, see [Programming with Quartz](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123694736). It's 8 years old now, and was originally written for OS X -- but that ultimately doesn't matter a whole lot because the fundamentals of the drawing system and APIs really haven't evolved significantly since then -- And that is what you intend to focus on. The APIs have been extended, so it would be good to review which APIs were introduced since 10.4 and see what problems they solve, but it's secretly a good thing for you because it helps maintain focus on the fundamental operation of the drawing system. Note that some functionalities were excluded from iOS (e.g. often due to floating point performance and memory constraints, I figure), so *every* example may not be usable on iOS, but I know of no better guide.

Tip: Your drawing code can be easily reused on OS X and iOS if you use Quartz rather than AppKit/UIKit. Plus, the Quartz APIs have a lower update frequency (i.e. the APIs tend to be longer lived).

Answer (score 2):

-drawRect: gets called at some point after you (e.g. your view controller) have called the view's method -setNeedsDisplay or -setNeedsDisplayInRect:.

Saving the graphics state pushes the current graphics state onto a stack. The graphics state contains fill and stroke setting, the current transformation matrix etc. See [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_overview/dq_overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH202-TPXREF132) for details.

The [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/) doesn't contain many examples but is otherwise quite thorough.

Comment: Short, simple, and exactly right, and with documentation to back it up, too. I would add that the [View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/) explains the mechanics of when and why `drawRect:` is called, and what exactly it's drawing into (TL;DR: the view's layer).

Comment: It covers some of the mechanics. The truth is a good deal more complex.

Answer (score 0):

With quartz/ core graphics the context is literally a set of current parameters to use to draw the next drawing command on top of the previous drawing.

Saving the state let's you save all those parameters for later drawing commands that will reuse them.

Then you can set up a different set of parameters for some drawing commands.

Restoring the state gets you back to where you were.

I recommend the book 
Programming with Quartz 
2D and PDF Graphics in Mac OS X

Though a bit dated in some ways, it will really teach you how quartz / core graphics really flows.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is a very very deep topic to talk about. I'll explain a few things to my understanding & try to keep it simple. If I'm mistaken I hope someone can correct me out.

first of all there is concept of onscreen drawing and offscreen drawing. On screen drawing is taken place in GPU where offscreen drawing is taken place in CPU to draw things and then its given to GPU to display on the screen. Thats where drawRect() comes in to place (drawrect is only 1 way of doing the offscreen drawings btw). This is why in the drawRect template method (you will see when you make a subclass of UIView) there is a comment by Apple telling

"Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing. An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation"

The reason is whenever there is drawRect method, the iOS would have to ask the CPU to takecare of the drawing which takes place in drawRect and hand it over to the GPU. (Dont get the idea that this is a bad thing :) ). So this is what happens in drawRect in an abstract level.

Now to the question of why save & restore same context over and over. Have you tried to read the description of the method in apple doc about save/restore context ? If you have, you'd notice that it shows all the graphical states which would be affected by this. Ok how does this help ?

Consider something like this. Lets say you're drawing on a rectangle where you have to limit  this next part of the drawing on the right half of it and use shadows and antialiasing, etc.    You can save your context before drawing the right side and set whatever properties you want and once you finish that, you can simply restore the context and you can continue with all the settings you had before without explicitly setting them again. It's a good practice as well when you do complex drawings as otherwise it would have weird outcomes you might not expect. something like this below

```
- drawRect() 
{
CGContextSaveGState(context);

drawLeftPart(); // - 1

drawRightPart(); // - 2 

someOtherDrawing(); // - 3

CGContextRestoreGState(context);

}

- drawLeftPart()
{
CGContextSaveGState(context);

// do your drawing 

CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}

- drawRightPart()
{
CGContextSaveGState(context);

// do your drawing 

CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}

- someOtherDrawing()
{
CGContextSaveGState(context);

// do your drawing 

CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Now what ever properties you set in part 1 wont affect drawing of part 2 & 3 so forth.

Hope this helps,