# ios viewcontroller view graph live with Mutable Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, view, uiviewcontroller

Good morning,

what I try to achieve is to draw a graph inside a view whilst data are being added live in the VC through an Array.

So far I have a VC and a view with its own class. Inside the class, inside drawRect I generate random numbers and they appear on the screen as dots. So far, so good.

What I want to do is generate the numbers in the ViewController (or get them via an external source), save them in a mutableArray, retrieve them inside the class and use them for the graph.

I found a similar question here on SO, from 2 years ago so there is no point commenting on it. The question was : I have on FirstViewController an array with float value. I need to pass to my View this array

The recommended solution, that was marked as working was :

In your FirstViewController.h write

```
#include <UIKit/UIKit.h>
extern NSArray *yourArray;
```

And in your FirstViewController.m write

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
@interface FirstViewController ()
@end
NSArray *yourArray;
```

Now you'll have to import the whole FirstViewController in your "MyView"-Class. Simply #import "FirstViewController.h" in MyView.m. After doing so, "yourArray" will be available in MyView.

I do exactly what it says, then I initialize my Array, put values in it, NSLog in VC to check all working fine and it does. When I try to retrieve one value in my view and NSLog it, it says the value in the array is (null).
The code is so simple I almost have nothing to show:

In my VC.h

```
extern NSMutableArray *yourArray;
```

In my VC.m implementation

```
NSMutableArray *yourArray;
```

In my VC.m viewDidLoad

```
NSMutableArray *yourArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[yourArray insertObject:@"Works" atIndex:0];
NSString *object = [yourArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog (@"the item in Array in VC is %@", object);
```

In my view.m

```
#import "GraphViewController.h"
```

And then I tried adding:

```
NSString *object = [yourArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog (@"the item in Array in View is %@", object);
```

in  (void)awakeFromNib, in (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame, in (void)updateValues and in (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect

It doesn't work from anywhere I put it. I am at a complete loss.

Could somebody please point me in the right direction ?

Thanks,

=============================================

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm gonna try and go through this bit by bit.

You have:
A subclass of UIViewController called GraphViewController.
A subclass of UIView called MyGraphView.
A storyboard.

In your storyboard you have a UIViewController scene which contains a UIView object.
In the "Identity Inspector" you have set the UIViewController scene "Custom Class" field to GraphViewController. Correct?
Also in the Identity Inspector you have set the UIView object Custom Class field to MyGraphView. Correct?

So when you right-click-drag from the View object to the header file of GraphViewController the pop up appears ready for you to input a property name and the "Type" field of that popup is already set to be MyGraphView. Correct?

After the IBOutlet property has been set you can select the GraphViewController in storyboard and show the Connections Inspector and see that there exists a referencing Outlet called MyGraphView connected to GraphViewController.?

So if all those are true then your viewController and View are set up in storyboard.

GraphViewController has a property which is an NSMutableArray called yourArray.
GraphViewController has a property which is an MyGraphView called myView.
MyGraphView has a property which is an NSArray called graphDataArray.

So in your GraphViewController paste this method above -viewDidLoad.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.yourArray = [@[@"Testing"] mutableCopy];
    if (self.myView == nil) {
        NSLog(@"The Instance of MyGraphView called MyView does not exist");
        return;
    }else{
        NSLog(@"The Instance of MyGraphView called MyView exists %@",self.myView);
    }
    self.myView.graphDataArray = [self.yourArray copy];
    if (self.myView.graphDataArray == nil) {
        NSLog(@"GraphDataArray is nil");
    }else {
        NSLog(@"Object at index 0 = %@",self.myView.graphDataArray[0]);
        NSLog(@"MyGraphView can now receive arrays from GraphViewController :]");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes to all the questions you asked. 
I had ended up putting   self.myView.graphDataArray = [self.yourArray copy]; in myViewDidLoad
Excepted the tests you run in viewDidAppear, I have the same code.
I don't think it comes from  VC. I have kept your viewDidAppear and removed the stuff in viewDidLoad, then inside myGraphView, in drawRect, I put if ([self.graphDataArray count] == 0) {
    NSLog (@"number of items in View graph %lu", (unsigned long)[self.graphDataArray count]);
        return;
    }
and it logs:  MyGraph5[5932:60b] number of items in View graph 0 although we put @"Testing" in it

Comment: When you run what is the nslog output from viewDidAppear? Does MyGraphView exist?

Comment: The Instance of MyGraphView called MyView exists <MyGraphView: 0x17d6f8a0; frame = (0 128; 320 365); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x17d6f9e0>>
2014-09-30 17:44:29.475 MyGraph5[5932:60b] Object at index 0 = Testing
2014-09-30 17:44:29.477 MyGraph5[5932:60b] MyGraphView can now receive arrays from GraphViewController :]

Comment: Okay try this, in -viewDidAppear, directly after the last two NSLog statements put [self.myView setNeedsDisplay]; and then see what the NSLog in your -drawRect method outputs.

Comment: still the same, number of items in ViewGraph is 0.

Comment: I know there isn't a lot of code on the MyGraphView but what do you think I could do wrong ? It must be a small thing.
The GraphDataArray doesn't need to be initialized as only being a copy of YourArray. Right ?

Comment: No idea what is wrong. Add this to your GraphViewController:    -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event{ NSLog(@"Self.myView.graphDataArray contents = %@",self.myView.graphDataArray);}                        Then build and run and when the app loads in the simulator tap the screen and see what comes up in the console logs and let me know.

Comment: If I run on simulator or on my Phone, NSLog is:
Self.myView.graphDataArray contents = (
    Testing
)
Could it be that in MyGraphView.m, my method 
if ([self.graphDataArray count] == 0) {
    NSLog (@"number of items in View graph %lu", (unsigned long)[self.graphDataArray count]);
        return;
    }
is called BEFORE we actually fill the array in the VC? If that were the case, then returning 0 would be the correct answer.
I really appreciate your help is trying to sort this out.

Comment: Reason I ask is  below is the order in NSLog :
2014-09-30 20:38:45.692 MyGraph5[10888:90b] number of items in View graph 0
2014-09-30 20:38:45.695 MyGraph5[10888:90b] The Instance of MyGraphView called MyView exists <MyGraphView: 0x8e2f020; frame = (0 128; 320 365); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x8e2f110>>
2014-09-30 20:38:45.696 MyGraph5[10888:90b] Object at index 0 = Testing
2014-09-30 20:38:45.696 MyGraph5[10888:90b] MyGraphView can now receive arrays from GraphViewController :]
2014-09-30 20:38:49.024 MyGraph5[10888:90b] Self.myView.graphDataArray contents = (
    Testing
)

Comment: Absolutely it could. That is the reason I had you call -setNeedsDisplay on your view. This makes your view call -drawRect again by which time the array in the view should have had data in it. So it should have logged it. Actually I've just realised why it didn't work. Your if statement in - drawRect only performs the log statement if the array is empty. If you change == to > then you should see the graphDataArray have contents before you tap the screen.

Comment: Yee Haw ! NSLog shows : number of items in View graph 1
So I guess I now can test with my NSNumbers and it should be fine. I am going to try and I will report back. You made my day, Kristian

Comment: OK, I am all messed up with the fact we defined an array with a strings and I need to go back to my numbers. I am tired now. I do it tomorrow and I will let you know. Again thank you so much for your help.x

Comment: You're welcome. Before you start tomorrow read this http://cocoaheads.tumblr.com/post/17757846453/objective-c-literals-for-nsdictionary-nsarray-and

Comment: Self.yourArray = @[@1,@23,@987,@42,@420];

Comment: If you are still around , I find out in Google that I can have several values at once like this
self.yourArray = [@[@"Testing",@"Trying",@"Sweating"] mutableCopy];It does work and I now shows the array count is 3, but for the life of me, I can't find out how to do the same for NSNumbers. I only manage one at a time 
[yourArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:535]];

and it doesn't work for whatever reason. Do you know how to do exactly this
self.yourArray = [@[@"Testing",@"Trying",@"Sweating"] mutableCopy];
but with NSNumbers?

Comment: OK, I managed. I have initialized the array with NSNumbers, I pick them back from my view and I draw my points. Fabulous !!!! I am going to test further tomorrow, but my impression is that if I don't initialize and fill the array in viewDidAppear but in ViewDidLoad, it doesn't work anymore. Is it correct that I need to do it in view Did Appear and would you know why ?

Comment: -viewDidLoad gets called before - viewDidAppear.  So your GraphView is not ready to accept an array. Leave your code in -viewDidAppear. Read up on "uiviewcontroller life cycle" Take a look at my last two comments for how to use NSNumber in an array. Read the article then look at the line of code I added.

Comment: Morning, NSNumbers work all fine.
I read about life cycle, very interesting. A question please : If I put the array values in ViewDidAppear manually, it's fine. What if I get the values from somewhere else, like I download them or I get them by tapping a button... I don't think I could do that code in viewDidLoad. Would I have to create a VC1 with my button and an array getting the values, then share this array in the vDA of VC2 (my current VC+view) and then share a copy of my array in the view in order to do my drawing. Seems very complicated.

Comment: You would want a separate method (IBAction) in your GraphViewController that gets called when you tap a button. You need to understand how to use methods, IBActions and getting objects to communicate with each other as they are some of the basics. I suggest you find some beginner tutorials online, there is plenty out there. You'll find the whole process a lot easier in the long run.

Comment: This doesn't make sense; why would you maintain a separate array for a graph when you can simply add the points to the array of points in a UIBezierPath?

See my answer below for a very simple solution...

Answer (score 0):

Okay so let's get the array working in the GraphViewController first and worry about the view afterwards.

It is easier to get rid of the code you used from the other stack overflow question and give you something new.

```
// in GraphViewController.m file
#import "GraphViewController.h"
@interface GraphViewController ()
// create a property that you can access elsewhere using self.yourArray
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *yourArray;
@end

@implementation GraphViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.yourArray = [@[@"Works1",@"Works2",@"StillWorks"] mutableCopy];
    NSLog (@"the item in Array in VC is %@", self.yourArray[0]);
    NSLog (@"the item in Array in VC is %@", self.yourArray[1]);
    NSLog (@"the item in Array in VC is %@", self.yourArray[2]);
}
```

The View Class

```
// In AAAView.h declare this property
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *graphDataArray;
```

Then when you want to pass the array from your ViewController to your view you can just do this

```
// yourAAAView is the instance of the view you have in your ViewController
yourAAAView.graphDataArray =  [self.dataArray copy];
```

//*******************************************

- Create an IBOutlet for your view in the GraphViewController, we'll call it "myView"
- In -viewDidLoad populate yourArray with the values you need to draw the dots.

  - If you are using floats, doubles or ints etc you need to wrap the values in NSNumber before they can be added to an array.
  - If you are using CGPoints you need to wrap the values in NSValue before they can be added to an array
- Once the array has all the values pass it to self.myView

  - self.myView.graphDataArray = self.yourArray;
- In YourView class -drawRect you need to get the values from self.graphDataArray and use them to draw your dots.

  - Check if the self.graphDataArray is nil and return if it is. No point trying to use an non-existent array.
  - I'm guessing you used a for loop originally so you will want to do something like this:

.

```
  for(int i = 0; i< [self.graphDataArray count]; i++) {
        // get object (NSNumber or NSValue) from array
             // NSNumber *num = self.graphDataArray[i];
             // NSValue *val = self.graphDataArray[i];
        // unwrap the value you stored in the object (float or CGpoint etc)
        // use those values to draw the dots the same way you did before
   }
```

Comment: Hello Kristian, thanks for your answer. Yes, this is no problem within the VC, it does work fine.

Comment: I am not sure I get it completely, if you could please explain.

What is the purpose of this method ?

-(void)acceptArrayOfGraphData:(NSArray*)array{
    self.graphDataArray = array;
}

The [yourView acceptArrayOfGraphData:self.yourArray]; goes into my VC, right ? In fact, I tried in both and get an error message in both. If I put into view it says Property Your Array not found. And if I put in VC, it says no know class method for selector acceptArrayOfGraphData

How do I get the array's values? The same way I do in the VC to NSLog them? And in which part of my View?

Comment: Sorry I probably made that more complicated than it needs to be for you purposes. I'll edit it.

Comment: To get values from the array in your AAAView you can use NSString *aString = self.graphDataArray[0]; the same as I did in the NSLog.

Comment: Sorry, I must be thick today ... or generally :-) but I don't get it.
I have a mutable array called YourArray in my VC (BTW the feeding of Works1, Works2... this way gives a warning message as Incompatible Pointer Types assigning to NSMutable Array from NSArray). 
Then in myView, I create a NSArray (non mutable) called GraphDataArray.
What is this story of yourAAAView being the instance of the view I have in my VC? What I did what just to bring a view on my Storyboard and to attach it to the ViewClass I created. I didn't create any instance of that view. Should I have ?

Comment: Okay my bad, I changed the yourArray property from NSArray to NSMutableArray and forgot to change in other places. So when you add @"Works1" etc I've made a change to the code so it creates a mutableArray instead and when you send the array to the AAAView you want to create a copy so that it is immutable. With regards to the view being in storyboard, that is fine but you will need a reference to it in your view controller so you can pass it an array, an IBOutlet property will work. How are you drawing your dots anyway?

Comment: I changed the dataArray in yourAAAView.graphDataArray =  [self.dataArray copy]; to  myView.graphDataArray =  [self.yourArray copy]; so now there is no warning anymore, but now I crash for something else probably with <GraphViewController 0x1556ebd0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key myView.'
I need to have a look at it, I will be back in a little while.

Comment: It doesn't want me to create an IBOutlet of my view. It says  Property with 'iboutlet' attribute must be an object type (invalid 'int *') and also Property with 'weak' attribute must be of object type. so I added this GraphView *myView; in my VC.m
I draw my points with random numbers using  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,
                                     [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 100, 100); .....

Comment: @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView *myView; Is the correct syntax.  Take a look at the edit I made to my answer, and see if you can follow it. I have to do some work now so you might need to google about NSNumber & NSValue. Good luck

Comment: Thank you Kristian, I am going to work on it and will report back later

Comment: Last question you might catch before you go : Do I create an IBOutlet from the UIView (before attaching it to the view class) or after ? I ask because I either get property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView *myView  or property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet GraphView *myView  May be it makes a difference ?

Comment: You're welcome, I'll check back later.  @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet GraphView *myView is correct that should be in the GraphViewController.

Comment: I am following your To Do List.
I have managed the array with NSNumbers and it works in VC with NSLog. The current problem is creating the

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet GraphView *myView;

It just doesn't want me to do it. I get this :

 Property with IBOutlet attribute must be an object type (invalid 'int*).

It doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: It looks like you've missed the pointer symbol * it should read ... GraphView *myView;

Comment: http://www.codetuition.com/ios-tutorials/connecting-iboutlets-ibactions-the-fast-way/

Comment: No I don't know why I lost it in here, but the pointer is there in my app. I can't post photos, but there is no doubt my pointer is there. I drag from the View to the VC via the Assistant editor. I have tried in.h and in.m, it allows me to do it then immediately shows me a yellow and a red warning. The only one it allows me to do without complaining is property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView *myView but then when I try your self.myView.graphDataArray = self.yourArray; it tells me it doesn't know what myView is.
My class GraphView is an Objective class based on UIView, that can't be wrong.

Comment: The exact error message when I use self.myView.graphDataArray = self.yourArray; (after defining myView via UIView) is :
property GraphDataArray not found on object of type 'UIView*'

Comment: Getting closer :-) but I think on the top of it, Xcode has something against me today...
I deleted my ViewClass and created a new one called MyGraphView. 
No more error messages with self.myView.graphDataArray = self.yourArray; but it doesn't work. When I run, I test if graphDataArray is empty and it is. 
That's how I fill yourArray   NSMutableArray *yourArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    
  [yourArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:370]]; ... 
I don't create a copy as we did before (as I don't know ho to do it in this case. Could it be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to maintain a separate array of points if you're going to render those points to a view. UIBezierPath maintains its own array of points. Instead of passing it an array of points, pass the points to the UIBezierPath object points array.

The following UIView code is all I use to render a graph, live and in real-time (30 times a second), as my Core Data database is updated with new records:

```
//
//  GraphView.h
//  DemonNetDAQClient
//
//  Created by James Bush on 5/3/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 James Bush. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

typedef void(^PointBlock)(id path);

@interface GraphView : UIView

- (void)addPoint:(PointBlock)block;

@end
```

In the UIView header file, I set up a block that passes a temporary UIBezierPath object to the UIViewController, which will create a path to append to the UIBezierPath that draws the graph in the UIView.

Here's my GraphView.m:

```
//
//  GraphView.m
//  DemonNetDAQClient
//
//  Created by James Bush on 5/3/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 James Bush. All rights reserved.
//

#import "GraphView.h"
#import "GraphViewController.h"

@interface GraphView ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIBezierPath *graph;

@end

@implementation GraphView

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [[UIColor redColor]setStroke];
    [self.graph stroke];
}

- (void)addPoint:(PointBlock)block {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        UIBezierPath *graphTmp = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
        [graphTmp moveToPoint:[self.graph currentPoint]];
        block(graphTmp);
        [self.graph appendPath:graphTmp];
    });
}

- (UIBezierPath *)graph {
    UIBezierPath *g = self->_graph;
    if (!g) {
        g = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
        [g moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))];
        self->_graph = g;
    }

    return g;
}

@end
```

Whenever a new object is inserted into my Core Data database (as detected by my NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate/UIViewController), the addPoint method is called. When called, the UIViewController is passed a block with a reference to the temporary UIBezierPath object created in the UIView to which it will add a point. When the block is returned to the UIView method, the newly configured, temporary UIBezierPath object is appended to the UIBezierPath that is rendered by the UIView. All your points data is maintained with that UIBezierPath object.

NOTE | I wrote a separate method that creates the UIBezierPath object to set it's first point to the proper location in the graph view, although I could have done this in two lines within the awakeFromNib method. I do this for compatibility with views on storyboards and views instantiated programmatically (you don't call awakeFromNib without a storyboard).

Following is the relevant UIViewController code that gets the point data from the NSFetchedResultsController (which I'm sure you recognize and are already familiar with, having worked with table view controllers—all the same thing):

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: {
            Metric *metric = (Metric *)anObject;
            double measurement = metric.metricMeasurement;
            CGFloat y = [self convertMetricToPoint:measurement];
            [(GraphView *)self.graphView addPoint:^(id path) {
                CGPoint newPoint = CGPointMake([path currentPoint].x + 1.0, y);
                [path addLineToPoint:newPoint];
                [path moveToPoint:newPoint];
            }];
            break;
        }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete: {

            break;
        }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate: {

            break;
        }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove: {

            break;
        }
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.graphView setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (CGFloat)convertMetricToPoint:(double)metric {
    double maxPointValue    = ([(NSNumber *)[self valueForKeyPath:@"fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects.@max.metricMeasurement"] doubleValue]);
    double normalizedMetric = (metric / maxPointValue) * self.graphView.frame.size.height;

    return (CGFloat)normalizedMetric;
}
```

Would you like to see this in action? [Here's a video](https://youtu.be/JYF2ZSEgOrg):

```html
<iframe width="1280" height="720" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JYF2ZSEgOrg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```